# If I add an @reply when editing a comment, does it trigger a notification?

Tags: support, comments, edits, notifications

It sometimes happens that I leave a comment on a post, meaning it as a reply to another user, but I forget to include a @reply string to notify the other user.

If I edit my comment (within the 5 minute window) to add the @reply string, will it cause the target user to be notified?